# Core Data - Deleting the object satisfying the condition

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have below two entities in my Core Data Model,

```
Client {id, name, ...other attributes}
Project {id, name, .... other attributes}
```

I have One to Many Relationship from Client to Project

```
Client.projects <------>> Project.client
```

Same project can be in two different Client objects

For example, If I have a Project object called projectA and two Client objects called clientA and clientB, both the clientA and clientB can have the same project ProjectA like this

```
clientA.projects =[projectA] and clientB.projects = [projectA]
```

My requirement is,

In UI I have a remove button, on click of the button I need to remove(delete the object from coreData) the project only if none of the other client objects have the project.

For example:

1 case: projectA and none of the clients have projectA, so in this case I can delete the projectA object

2 case: projectA and clientA has this project, so in this case I cannot delete the projectA object.

How do I set the predicate for the above case, so that it should delete or notDelete based on predicate?

I'm using Swift 3.1

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: A client can have multiple projects and a project can have multiple clients? That sounds like a many to many relationship. Can you post a picture of the graphical core data model?

Comment: @keithbhunter I've added a graphical core data model picture.

Comment: That looks like a project can only have one client associated with it. So if X number of clients can have a reference to ProjectA, then there are X copies of ProjectA in Core Data. Perhaps a many-to-many would work better here so there is only one ProjectA in Core Data. With that in mind, you can use the [Core Data delete rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html) to handle deleting objects appropriately.

Comment: @keithbhunter ok, I'll change the model and try to make this work. Thanks for your help.